# Specify end of regex group

Tags: regex, regex-group

I am trying to create a regular expression which matches multiple groups, so the values between the groups can be extracted. Each group looks identical.

Lets consider the following example, note that the linebreaks are intended:

```
dog 1
wuff
wuff
cat
123
XYZ
dog 1
wuff
wuff
cat
456
ABC
dog 1
wuff
wuff
cat
789
```

Thus, with the right regular expression I want to get the output:

```
123
XYZ
456
ABC
789
```

On regex101.com I tried:

```
(?s)(?:dog.*cat)
```

which matches all values between the first occurence of dog an the last occurence of cat.

In addition I tried:

```
(?s)(?:dog.*(cat){1})
```

which, with my limited knowledge, should match the first occurence of cat and then end the group, but it does not.

I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use this regex in MULTILINE mode to capture value after `dog.*cat` matches:

```sh
^dog\b(?:.*\n)+?cat\n(.*(?:\n.*)*?)(?=\ndog|\Z)
```

Your values are present in capture group #1

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Jal0Vj/3)

**RegEx Details:**

- `^`: Match start line
- `dog\b`: Match word `dog` with a word boundary
- `(?:.*\n)+?`: Match anything followed by a line break. Repeat this 1+ times (lazy)
- `cat\n`: Match `cat` followed by a newline
- `(.*(?:\n.*)*?)`: These are the multiline values you're interested in the first capture group.
- `(?=\ndog|\Z)`: Lookahead to assert that we have a `dog` after line break or end of input ahead of the current position

Comment: That is very good answer, thanks a lot! I have done a small fault. If after 123 there is another line which contains XYZ how do I take this into consideration with ```(.+)```?

Comment: Can you please update the question with this example and show expected output so that I can update my regex

Comment: Sure! I am sorry for the inconvenience. I simplified my problem too much. I updated it.

Comment: I believe this is what the OP needs. I tried your regex with [some more inputs](https://regex101.com/r/xhoqcI/1) and it worked perfectly.